# How to select specific XML node in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

**XML,**

```
 <A>
    <B  id="ABC">
      <C name="A" />
      <C name="B" />
      <C name="C" />
      <C name="G" />
    </B>
    <B id="ZYZ">
      <C name="1" />
      <C name="2" />
      <C name="3" />
      <C name="4" />
    </B>
  </A>
```

I Need to select only `<C>` nodes and assign to a variable.

I'm using following **c#** code which is not working,

`var asdf = c.Elements("C");`

`asdf` should contain ,

```
<C name="A" />
<C name="B" />
<C name="C" />
<C name="G" />
<C name="1" />
<C name="2" />
<C name="3" />
<C name="4" />
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is `c` here? You haven't given us enough context. It sounds like you're just looking for the `Descendants("C")` method instead of `Elements("C")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Descendants` like:

```
var cNodes = document.Descendants("C");
```

For output:

```
foreach (var item in cNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

You will get:

```
<C name="A" />
<C name="B" />
<C name="C" />
<C name="G" />
<C name="1" />
<C name="2" />
<C name="3" />
<C name="4" />
```

Answer (score 2):

this run:

```
XElement x = XElement.Parse("your_xml_string");

var asdf=x.Elements("B").Elements("C");
```

Comment: TLama what is changed with your edit? Excuse me but I new here.